Does adding random null values to features at train time make models less 'sensitive' to those?
I know that there are several hyperparameters one can set to make models less "sensitive" to signal and therefore more robust and better at out-of-sample generalization.
But I'm interested in ways to make models less sensitive to some features by hacking the data, specifically, by changing feature values to nulls and/or random values, at random. I'm interested in making models (gradient boosted trees such as LGBM) more robust against adversarial attacks
Would randomly replacing some feature values with Nulls/missing (or even random values) help with that?
My intuition is that random/missing values at random in some features would make models not trust those features so much -- and therefore decrease the feature importance and make the models less vulnerable to adversarial attacks in those features at in production.
Does this make sense? I couldn't find much about this in the literature. I know about dropout, which makes the model dumber to achieve regularization, but it's changing the weights/neurons and not the data itself. Also, I never this this mentioned outside the scope of deep Neural Nets.

This is a nice question (+1), I have considered it myself in the past too.

It makes some sense to use random values. In a way, what you are "rediscovering" is the simple ridge estimator $(X^TX +\lambda I)^{-1}$ for regression tasks.
In the context of regression, and assume that by random values we mean $X_{noisy} = X_{real} + N(0,\lambda^2I)$: when we are adding uncorrelated noise to our features $X$, that noise will essentially amplify the diagonal of our covariance matrix, while at the same time push the off-diagonal elements to become lower  (actually $X^TX$ is the Gram matrix, but it is the functional equivalent of the covariance matrix here). That regularisation indeed assists the generalisability of our ridge regression but can also lead to underfitting (ergo we usually pick the regularisation parameter $\lambda$ via some cross-validation schema). Obviously, as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ we get no signal as the noise variance dominates.
Particular to XGBoost: the $\lambda$  parameter of the $L_2$ regularisation doesn't regularise the sample in an equivalent way as the one described above. XGBoost regularises the cost function directly by penalizing via the weights, weights effectively being the average of the true labels at each leaf.
In general, if we are worried about the data being overfitted, then we might consider the gamma and min_child_weight XGBoost parameters as a more principled approach in making our booster "trust single points less". The gamma prevents the booster from making a split unless it is indeed very informative and min_child_weight effectively forces the leaf weight to be more holistic as it is aggregates over more sample points. Both will have similar effect to "noising" the sample but allow us a more fine-tuned approach.
To also address the other option mentioned too: It makes little sense to use null values. Null values will either have to be imputed (i.e. we just added some additional dependencies in our analysis just to replace a real feature value with some conditional mean of it) or removed (to quote directly from XGBoost docs: "When the missing parameter is specified, values in the input predictor that is equal to missing will be treated as missing and removed." - i.e. we just reduced our sample). So, yeah, I wouldn't recommend nullifying random feature values in a sample unless there is some other reason (e.g. we have fully observed training data, but we know that during deployment we get a lot of missing values so we try to emulate the missingness mechanism.)

Awesome answer! Thanks

Happy to help! Thank you for your kind words. :)

The ideas about the native XGBoost regularization parameters is a good suggestion but I believe that gets applied to every feature, right? Ideally, I would like to make the model less sensitive to some features but not others. I think I'll try both approaches and see what happens =)

Yes, correct. As a general pointer, in terms of linear models, there is a regularisation technique called "Group LASSO" that regularised features unevenly - it might give you some further ideas.
